# adding item to dynamic list (apple shortcuts)

Tags: ios, shortcut

I have an apple shortcut that selects the next items from my calender and shows me a list to select from. When I select an item I'm shown the time it takes to get to that appointment and gives me the option to plan a route (using maps or google maps). This works great.

I would like to add a static address to this list to always have a "speed dial" to plan a route to that address (home for example). Is this possible?

Comment: I am not aware of any way to add items to a list afterwards. I have other ideas though. Would it be feasible to replace this list with a dictionary? There seem to be more options available with dictionaries, like "set dictionary value" --> you could easily append or prepend perhaps this dictionary. You'd have to eg. bind the current list values to some keys.

Comment: Are you able to transfer the dictionary to notes?

Answer (score 0):

Shortcut Lists are immutable. You can create a new List from an existing List and add additional items.

Note also that the Mac Shortcuts App (v14.1) interface doesn't allow this; use iOS to set it up.

Demo: https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/0f05cb15324e43a28a6336317eedd7c0